# Mysql REGEXP pattern SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, select

I want to achieve the below, written in pseudo mysql code.

Database Table (`protected_paths.tbl`):

```
ID  Path_Protected

1   /home/folder/private

2   /home/folder2/another-private

3   /home/folder3/subfolder/another/private-folder

4   /home/folder4/my_protected_folder
```

Input string:

```
Test | Match | String

1 | Y | /home/folder/private/another (caught by ID 1 above)

2 | Y | /home/folder/private/another/more (also caught by ID 1 above)

3 | N | /home/folder/work (not matched in table above)

4 | N | /home/folder/another-private (not matched in table above)

5 | N | /home/folder3/subfolder (not matched in table above - table above, ID 3, refers to deeper path)
```

Won't work, obviously:

```
SELECT * FROM `protected_paths` WHERE Path_Protected = '/home/folder/private/another';

SELECT * FROM `protected_paths` WHERE Path_Protected REGEXP '/home/folder/private/another';
```

(I want this to match ID 1 in protected_paths.tbl because it contains at least all of the string)

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers, Darryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you need a `REXEXP` for this or not.  You should be able to accomplish this with `LIKE` and `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM protected_paths 
WHERE '/home/folder/private/another' LIKE CONCAT('%',Path_Protected,'%')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d05c36/1)

Comment: left side `%` is not OP wanted i guess!

Comment: @SabujHassan -- Not sure... OP states `contains at least all of the string` which would include the left side...  Gets the point across either way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be fast if you have lots of rows, but this will work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)<>0 
  from tbl 
 where 'test-string' LIKE CONCAT(path_protected,'%')
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6023/3/0